# How to use serde json on a variable key name on top level

Tags: rust, serde

I'm having trouble finding a solution to when a key on the top level of the json is dynamic. In the JSON pasted below there are several dynamic keys, the date key is solved in the struct by HashMap<String, Type>. But this is not an option for a top level key, which here is "Time Series (5min)" Where the 5 min is dynamic based on interval.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

```rust
#[derive(Default, Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct TimeSeries5M {
    #[serde(rename(deserialize = "Meta Data", serialize = "metaData"))]
    pub meta_data: MetaData,
    #[serde(rename(deserialize = "Time Series (5min)", serialize = "timeSeries"))]
    pub time_series_5min: HashMap<String, TimeSeriesItem>,
}
```

```json
{
        "Meta Data": {
            "1. Information": "Intraday (5min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
            "2. Symbol": "IBM",
            "3. Last Refreshed": "2022-11-15 16:15:00",
            "4. Interval": "5min",
            "5. Output Size": "Compact",
            "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
        },
        "Time Series (5min)": {
            "2022-11-15 16:15:00": {
                "1. open": "144.3400",
                "2. high": "144.3400",
                "3. low": "144.3400",
                "4. close": "144.3400",
                "5. volume": "4464"
            }
         }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think a top level `HashMap` is not possible? See this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c1ee20db52776a7e403b2137473cbf17)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to use `serde(flatten)` so you get the metadata separately and the rest goes in the hashmap:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct TimeSeries {
    #[serde(rename = "Meta Data")]
    meta_data: MetaData,

    #[serde(flatten)]
    time_series: HashMap<String, HashMap<String, TimeSeriesItem>>,
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f112ea0a7ea4467772709a791b0a2ced)